# Android ListView in TabHost hangs

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost

I've got an Activity with a TabHost with 3 tabs. The activity associated with one of the tabs, has a ListView in its layout. It is due to this ListView, that moving between tabs doesn't work (it other tabs do not respond). When I remove the ListView, all the tabs work (i.e they respond to clicks). But I need a ListView within a tab.

My MainActivity has this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Resources ressources = getResources();
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Android tab
        Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, ScanQrActivity.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Scan QR")
                .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_scanqr_config))
                .setContent(intentAndroid);

        // Apple tab
        Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, HistoryActivity.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("History")
                .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_history_config))
                .setContent(intentApple);

        // Windows tab
        Intent intentWindows = new Intent().setClass(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecWindows = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Settings")
                .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_settings_config))
                .setContent(intentWindows);

        // add all tabs
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecApple);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecWindows);

        //set Scan QR tab as default (zero based)
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
```

The HistoryActivity has this layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="History"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/historyLabel"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/historyList" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is due to the ListView in this layout file, that the tabs are unresponsive.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials for sliding tabs with `ViewPager+TableLayout` and others too. Compare to `ListView` , `RecyclerView` is much better than it. So prefer it.

Comment: Try using Fragments with Recycleview. thats more better